# Specify the port when running dotnet myapp.dll

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

I am looking for something like this.

```
/usr/bin/dotnet myapp1.dll --port 5001
/usr/bin/dotnet myapp2.dll --port 5002
```

We are starting the `dotnet` process with `systemd` and using `nginx` as our reverse proxy.

I have seen these GitHub issues and am concerned that port specification from the command line isn't something the .NET Core team supports:

- https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639#issuecomment-237721352
- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5912

Comment: I’m sure you must’ve ruled it out, but what stops you from using something like `—urls http://*:5001`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I didn't know that would work. I ended up using `--server.urls` and modifying the Program.cs to use command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem today, and debugging my application from the console, I did the following command line:

```
dotnet AppName.dll --urls http://*:5001
```

The reason I added the customer port, is that the application is already running on whatever default port, so running it again on the same port is not possible.

This is the console snapshot:

[image]